# Pass in the object a java class is embedded in as a parameter

Tags: java, android, class, inner-classes

I'm building an android application, which has a list view, and in the list view, a click listener, containing an onItemClick method.  So I have something like this:

```
public class myList extends ListActivity {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            /* Do something*/
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, this works fine.  However, many times I find myself needing too preform an application using the outer class as a context.  thusfar, I've used:

```
parent.getContext();
```

to do this, but I would like to know, is that a bad idea?  I can't really call:

```
super
```

because it's not really a subclass, just an embedded one.  So is there any better way, or is that considered cosure?  Also, if it is the right way, what should I do if the embedded method doesn't have a parameter to get the outside class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to call the outer class from within the anonymous inner class, right? To do so, use the following syntax:

```
myList.this.getContext();
```

from within the `onItemClick` method of the anonymous inner class. This is the special syntax defined for an inner class to access the instance of the outer class that contains it.

Answer (score 2):

Within an anonymous inner class you can get the handle of the outer class with EnclosingClass.this. For info see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses). 
Long and short of it is you can use myList.this.getContext() in your onItemClick() ect.